# "The only things" or "the only thing"

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about a sentence talking about a kind of food.

When you are talking about someone who has eaten only chicken nuggets for many months, which sentence can you use?

> Chicken nuggets are the only **things** he eats nowadays.
>
> Chicken nuggets are the only **thing** he eats nowadays.

At first I thought it should be "the only things" because "chicken nuggets" are plural, but then I thought it could be "the only thing" because it is the kind of food that's discussed in the sentence, and chicken nuggets are just one kind of food.

Comment: Will you be visiting him in hospital?

Comment: I copied the wrong link earlier - this is the one I meant: [Is it 'thing' or 'things'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/149092/9161)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of these would be possible

Chicken nuggets are the only things he eats nowadays.

Chicken nuggets is the only thing he eats nowadays.